# jQuery is interfering with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a site for a client and I'm using a pre-build theme as a starting place.  It came with a js file that has an on click function for the mobile nav, everything was working fine, but when I added a script tag for jQuery the mobile nav broke and the console is giving this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`  How can I fix this? The js line that causes the error is `document.getElementById('mobile-navigation').onclick = function(){`
I tries changing that one line to use jQuery to select the element but that just caused another error further down in the js file.  How can I fix this?

in the html:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <span id="mobile-navigation">&nbsp;</span>
    <h1 class="nav-h1"><a href="index.html" class="logo"><!-- <img src="images/logo.png" alt=""> -->Header</a></h1>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="selected navList">
            <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navList">
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navList">
            <a ui-sref="find">Find a Vendor</a>
            <!-- <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="runningsinglepost.html">Running single post</a>
                </li>
            </ul> -->
        </li>
        <!-- <li>
            <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="blogsinglepost.html">blog single post</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li> -->
        <li class="navList">
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The js:

```
window.onload = function(){
            var getNavi = document.getElementById('menu');
            document.getElementById('mobile-navigation').onclick = function(){
                var a = getNavi.getAttribute('style');
                if(a){
                    getNavi.removeAttribute('style');
                    document.getElementById('mobile-navigation').style.backgroundImage='url(images/mobile/mobile-menu.png)';
                } else {
                    getNavi.style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById('mobile-navigation').style.backgroundImage='url(images/mobile/mobile-close.png)';
                }
            };
            var getElm = getNavi.getElementsByTagName("LI");
            for(var i=0;i<getElm.length;i++){
                if(getElm[i].children.length>1){
                    var smenu = document.createElement("span");
                    smenu.setAttribute("class","mobile-submenu");
                    smenu.setAttribute("OnClick","submenu("+i+")");
                    getElm[i].appendChild(smenu);
                };
            };
            submenu = function (i){
                var sub = getElm[i].children[1];
                var b = sub.getAttribute('style');
                if(b){
                    sub.removeAttribute('style');
                    getElm[i].lastChild.style.backgroundImage='url(images/mobile/mobile-expand.png)';
                    getElm[i].lastChild.style.backgroundColor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)';
                } else {
                    sub.style.display='block';
                    getElm[i].lastChild.style.backgroundImage='url(images/mobile/mobile-collapse.png)';
                    getElm[i].lastChild.style.backgroundColor='rgba(248, 98, 130, 0.8)';
                }
            };
        };
```

The jQuery script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

mobile.js script tag:

```
<script src="./js/mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It may be helpful to note I'm doing this in angular and the navbar is ng-included in the index.

Comment: It appears you are missing an element with the id of 'mobile-navigation'. Stuff `<div id='mobile-navigation'></div>` in the HTML and I bet the error goes away.

OR, you didn't close the script tag when you added jQuery.

Comment: I already have this in my html `<span id="mobile-navigation">&nbsp;</span>`, like I said, the script was working until I added jQuery

Comment: can you add more details? how the script tag you've added looks like? how the html looks like > and the context where the js line above has been called

Comment: if page having error is view-able would be great!

Comment: I added the html and the js, unfortunately it is not viewable, its only running locally on my machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect that your javascript is running before the document has loaded. This means that the javascript can't find the object, because it doesn't exist yet. Try using `document.onload` instead of `window.onload`.

Comment: Ok, that sort of helped, now the error is gone, but the mobile nav is still not working, no errors in the console

Comment: Ah, I see. That was problem #1. Now I believe you are overwriting the original `onclick` function. You can either add to the original, or use jQuery for the function. `$('#mobile-navigation').on('click', function () { /**/ }`. jQuery won't overwrite the original handler.

Comment: Added that, the menu is still not opening when clicked.

Comment: I changed my mobile.js back to the original and moved the jquery to be at the end of my body tag and the menu started working but materilize js stopped working becasue it was loaded before jQuery, so i moved that down to below the jquery and the menu broke again, so the materilize js might be causing an issue too

Comment: It sounds like your js files have conflicting handlers.